# Node.js on uclibc and arm support

Tags: linux, node.js, buildroot

I'm building an embedded system using buildroot and i want to replace nginx+php with node.js.

My system is using eglibc but i want to reduce the size of the system so i want to switch to uclibc. node.js can be compiled using uclibc-0.9.32-nptl?

More, while my current test hardware is x86 based, alix, i'll switch, in a couple of months, to a plug computer, that is arm based.
Will node.js works on arm based hardware?

Comment: It's been reported node runs on android which runs on arm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is built in an [OpenEmbedded recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/cgit.cgi/openembedded/tree/recipes/nodejs), you should be able to build it in Buildroot (with some adaptation to transform bitbake script to makefile one), yet nothing limit node.js to be compiled on an ARM platform or with a uclibc (at least till version 0.4.2).

Answer (score 5):

Just for your interest: I compile Node.js 0.4.7 on sheevaplug just taking into account

> http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=836
>
> https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/883

Enjoy!